# C# Wcf Web API Deserializing Response

Tags: c#, unit-testing, serialization, wcf-web-api

I am trying to unit test a web service that returns a non primitive. The response can be either xml or json depending on the request. In my test it'd be great if I could deserialize the content body to one of my objects. Here's some code:

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{arg1}/{arg2}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage<MyType> GetSomethingCool(string arg1, long arg2)
    {    
         return new HttpResonseMessage<MyTpe>(new MyType());
    }

    public class MyType
    {
         public string Property1 { get; set; }
         public long Property2 { get; set; }
         public string Property3 { get; set; }
    }
```

And my test:

```
    [Test]
    public void MyTestForTheWebService_ReturnsText()
    {
          Service1 service = new  Service1 (_mockRepository.Object);
          HttpResponseMessage<MyType> result = service.GetSomethingCool("Something", **);

          Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);

          MyType resultContent = result.Content.ReadAs<MyType>(); // doesn't work
          Assert.AreEqual("expected value", resultContent .Property1);
          .....
```

So basically I need to be able to turn result.Content to a MyType and don't know how. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
MyType resultContent = (MyType)result.Content.ReadAs();
```

I believe you are running into a known bug.

Comment: fantastic, works like a charm. I take it my code should have worked but this is a bug and will be fixed in future versions?

Comment: @NoahHeldman Not in my copy it hasn't.  It's in the HttpContentExtensionMethods class.

Comment: I am using Preview 5 released on 15 Sept, Getting exception in same line with msg- "<ArrayOfObjectName xmlns='http://www.xyz.com/IHH'>" was not expected. Also my Services are writting using WCF-REST but client is using WebAPI

Comment: Wcf-rest uses data contract serializer by default, whereas web API uses xmlserializer by default.  You need to change one of them.